# How to configure Magento downloader?

Tags: magento, pear

I'm trying to use Downloader from a previous Magento application but I got an error because the path doesn't meet my environement:

```
ERROR: failed to mkdir /var/www/domain.tld/app/locale/en_US
```

But my websites are not located here.

How could I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try deleting downloader/connect.cfg and login your admin's connect manager, it should recreate a new one with the correct path.